# How do I query for geometries in a rectangle bigger than what I request?

Tags: postgis, intersection, bounding-box

I have this PostGIS query:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geom_geojson 
FROM tracts AS tbl 
WHERE ST_MakeEnvelope(-86.84422306060793,36.14537465258748,-86.76182559967043,36.17846331773539) && ST_Transform(tbl.geom,4326);
```

This returns geometries in a rectangle made by those four points, but I'd like to get back geometries within a rectangle that's one kilometer bigger than that. What PostGIS query must I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ST_DWithin` on the geography type. If you have an index on `tbl.geom::geography` it'll use it. Or, you can store the tbl.geom as geography, and then you only have to have an index on the column.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geom_geojson 
FROM tracts AS tbl 
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  tbl.geom::geography,
  ST_MakeEnvelope(
    -86.84422306060793,
    36.14537465258748,
    -86.76182559967043,
    36.17846331773539
  ),
  1000
);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `1000` means 1000 meters?